# Maven ignoring provided scope for javax.mail

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a EAR with a number of EJB dependencies. 1 of these have a provided scope dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

but inside the jar there is the jar mail-1.4.3.jar (I dependency i previously deleted)

I've tried with:

```
mvn eclipse:clean
mvn dependency:tree
mvn dependency:analyze-only
```

but there is no way to get rid if this jar, that cause me a `java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.Session cannot be cast to javax.mail.Session in the server

Here the full pom.xml:

```
<!--
  ~ Copyright 2010-2012, CloudBees Inc.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>localdomain.localhost</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>conFloorApp</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Apache JSTL implementation -->
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <!--
                    use javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api, exclude this one
                    -->
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- used for the troubleshooting jsp datasource-mysql.jsp -->
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.27</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoip-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-webdav</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                     <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-maven-clickstart.git</connection>
      <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>community-release</id>
            <url>dav:https://repository-community.forge.cloudbees.com/release/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>community-snapshot</id>
            <url>dav:https://repository-community.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong spot. Here is the dependency tree for your pom. As per the dependency tree this pom is not pulling mail.jar you need to elsewhere. look at some other projects that may be pulling mail.jar as their dependency.

**Command to check dependency tree**

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

**Note there is only one entry of mail.jar that is marked as provided so this pom is not a issue**

```
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided
```

**Complete Output of dependency tree**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building conFloorApp 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ myApp ---
[INFO] localdomain.localhost:myApp:war:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - scope updated from test; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.27:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1)
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[INFO] +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.8.4.5:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-aspects:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.maxmind.geoip:geoip-api:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] \- com.github.dandelion:datatables-jsp:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO]    +- com.github.dandelion:datatables-core:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- (junit:junit:jar:4.10:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.8.1)
[INFO]    |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1)
[INFO]    \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.611s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 23 21:55:07 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```